# Improving Kafka Producer Performance: Using Multiple Kafka Templates vs. a Single Template with Dynamic Topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm working on an application that needs to send records to different topics within the same Kafka cluster. I've explored two approaches to achieve this, but I'm unsure about their impact on performance.

#### Single Kafka Template with Dynamic Topic

I'm currently using a single Kafka template in my application, where I specify the topic dynamically when sending records. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class ProducerService {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topic, GenericRecord key, GenericRecord value) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, value);
    }
}
```

This approach allows me to reuse the same Kafka template for multiple topics by passing the topic dynamically. However, I'm concerned about its impact on performance.

### Multiple Kafka Templates for Different Topics:

Alternatively, I'm considering using separate Kafka templates for each topic. Here's how I've implemented it

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    // Define topics
    @Value("${kafka.topic.first}")
    private String firstTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.second}")
    private String secondTopic;

    @Bean(name = "firstKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> firstKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> defaultKafkaProducerFactory) {
        KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(defaultKafkaProducerFactory);
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(firstTopic);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }

    // Second Kafka template bean definition follows similarly
}

class ProducerService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstKafkaTemplate")
    private KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> firstTopicTemplate;

    // Second Kafka template injection follows similarly

    public void send(String topic, GenericRecord key, GenericRecord value) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> future;
        if ("first".equalsIgnoreCase(topic)) {
            future = firstTopicTemplate.sendDefault(key, value);
        } else if ("second".equalsIgnoreCase(topic)) {
            future = secondTopicTemplate.sendDefault(key, value);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Topic is not configured");
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup, each topic has its own dedicated Kafka template. Would this approach yield better performance compared to the dynamic topic approach?

I understand that Kafka internally performs batch processing and sends batches to Kafka via a separate thread. Considering this, which approach would be more efficient in terms of performance? Or would there be negligible performance differences between the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

## Improving Kafka Producer Performance: Optimizing Parameters and Scaling Producers

After experimenting with different configurations and setups, I've found some insights that might help others facing similar challenges in Kafka producer performance optimization.

### Single Producer Efficiency:

In many cases, using a single Kafka producer can be efficient. However, if you encounter timeout issues due to the rapid queueing of records, tweaking certain parameters might alleviate the problem.

1. request.timeout.ms: This parameter controls how long the producer waits for a reply from the server when sending data. Adjusting this timeout can mitigate timeout errors.
2. linger.ms: By setting this parameter, you can control the time the producer waits for additional messages before sending the current batch. Although it increases latency, it also boosts throughput.
3. batch.size: This parameter determines the memory allocated for each batch of messages sent to the same partition. Adjust it carefully to balance memory usage and message frequency.
4. delivery.timeout.ms: An upper limit on the time to report success or failure after a send() call. Ensure it's appropriately set to avoid unnecessary delays.

If you're still facing timeout issues after optimizing these parameters, scaling up the number of producers might be necessary.

### Scaling Producers:

To increase the number of producers dynamically based on workload, consider using multiple threads with the same Kafka template.

1. Configure a TaskExecutor to manage the number of threads used for producing messages.
2. Enable the setProducerPerThread option in your ProducerFactory to allow each thread to have its own producer.

```
@Configuration
public class Conf {

    @Bean("kafkaTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getKafkaAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Kafka-Async-");
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> producerFactory) {
        if (producerFactory instanceof DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> defaultFactory) {
            defaultFactory.setProducerPerThread(true);
        }
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }
}
```

3. Implement an AsyncProducer class that utilizes the configured TaskExecutor to send messages asynchronously. This setup dynamically scales the number of producers based on workload.

```
class AsyncProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducer producer;

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("kafkaTaskExecutor")
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public void sendAsync(GenericRecord key, GenericRecord value) {
        CompletableFuture.completeFuture(value).thenAcceptAsync(val -> producer.send(topic, key, value), taskExecutor);
    }
}
```

By implementing this approach, you can ensure that your Kafka producers efficiently handle varying workloads without compromising performance.

### Conclusion

While using multiple Kafka templates might seem like an alternative, I found that optimizing parameters and scaling producers based on workload effectively addressed performance issues in my scenario.

However, every use case is unique, so I encourage experimentation and performance testing to determine the best approach for your specific requirements.

I hope this answer provides valuable insights and helps improve Kafka producer performance in your applications.